# Finding multiple integral on bounded area.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Today I just learn on multiple integral. Somehow this question quite confusing.

1. Find the area of the 1st quadrant region bounded by the curves y=$x^3$, y=2$x^3$ and x=$y^3$, x=4$y^3$ using subsitution method (Jacobbian method).

Let y=$u$$x^3$ and x=$v$$y^3$

Could someone please help me some steps on how to do by changing the variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise in computing a Jacobian:

$$dx \, dy = |J(u,v)| du \, dv$$

where

$$J = \det{\left (\begin{array}\\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{array}\right )}$$

$u=y/x^3$ and $v=x/y^3$ implies

$$ x=u^{-3/8} v^{-1/8} \quad y=u^{-1/8} v^{-3/8} $$

Compute the Jacobian from this.  Next, what are the bounds on $u$ and $v$?  You should be able to see that $u \in [1,2]$ and $v \in [1,4]$ from the bounds given to you.  The area is then

$$\int_1^2 du \, \int_1^4 dv \, |J(u,v)|$$

I get as an answer $(2-\sqrt{2})/8$.

Comment: :how you get $$ x=u^{-3/8} v^{-1/8} \quad y=u^{-1/8} v^{-3/8} $$

Comment: @Garett: algebra: substitute the expression for $y$ into the other expression and solve for $x$.

Comment: I still unable to get that algebra. Could pls help me out?

Comment: $$y=u x^3 \implies x = v (u x^3)^3 = v u^3 x^9$$  so that $$1=v u^3 x^8$$ Solve for $x$.

Comment: Alright thanks Ron Gordon. I manage to solve it at last. Thanks for your kind help =)